# shell script substring specified number of characters before a character

Tags: shell

I have a string in shell script as below and I want to parse only `2021-09-24` out of it. That is 10 characters before . character.

```
Output="ExecutionMsg: Query executed successfully with output:The Oracle base has been set to /u02/app/oracle\n\n\nEXPIRYDATE\n----------\n2021-09-24. "
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi looks like your sting is in multiple lines (\n characters in the data)

so you want the first 10 characters from the last line

get the last line with (-1 = last one line)

```
echo $Output | tail -1
```

and the first 10 characters of that with cut:

```
echo $Output | tail -1 | cut -c 1-10
```

Comment: tail -1 returns the whole string only.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: It is RHEL 8 version

Comment: interesting, that works on my ubuntu setup it you run `echo "ExecutionMsg: Query executed successfully with output:The Oracle base has been set to /u02/app/oracle\n\n\nEXPIRYDATE\n----------\n2021-09-24. " | tail -1`  I get `2021-09-24.`

Comment: perhaps run a `man tail` and look for the option to set the number of lines maybe `tail --lines 1` ?